# How to make the fontsize of list of table smaller?

Tags: lists

I have met a problem about how to make the fontsize of list of table smaller?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}
\geometry{top=1.4in,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{Tables}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering 
    \small{\caption{Cal}}
        \begin{tabular}{llll} 
            \toprule
            Par& Desc & Va & \\ 
            \midrule
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: `\small` does not take arguments so `\small{\caption...` does not make sense. You can adjust TOC related stuff using the `tocloft` package

Answer (score 3):

Using `tocloft`, you can add to the preamble the following three lines:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftlottitlefont{\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cfttabfont{\small}
\renewcommand\cfttabpagefont{\small}
```

with which you can change the fonts for title, items, and page, respectively. Here is the effect of using the three commands:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the entries to be smaller, put a `\small` before it (this doesn't change the caption):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{indentfirst,amsmath,multicol,amssymb,booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}
\geometry{top=1.4in,bottom=1.in,left=1in,right=1in}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
{\small\listoftables}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\section{Tables}
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering 
    \small{\caption{Cal}}
        \begin{tabular}{llll} 
            \toprule
            Par& Desc & Va & \\ 
            \midrule
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

For more advanced formatting there is the `tocloft`-package or the `tocbasic`-package of KOMA-script.